# Check if there any duplicates in ArrayList. Using Loop

Tags: java, for-loop, duplicates

Basically, the user enters numbers, the program should terminate after the user enters a duplicate number, and print all the entered integers except the last duplicate one, and print the duplicate input in a separate line.

```
Scanner keyBoard=new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        ArrayList<Integer>numbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i=0;i<6;i++){
            System.out.print("Number "+(i+1)+" : ");
            number=keyBoard.nextInt();
            numbers.add(number);
            for (int j=0;j<numbers.size();j++){
                if (numbers.get(j) == number) {
                    System.out.print(number+" is adplicate");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int k=0;k<1;k++){
            System.out.print(numbers);

        }
```

Comment: If you write a duplicate number. the program will stop and write all number without the last one

Comment: You spelled "duplicate" in 3 different ways - perhaps take some time to review your code. While you're at it - could you *include a question*? All you've done is paste your code with a vague description of what it should do.

Comment: Why are you using the class `Boolean` instead of the primitive `boolean`?

Comment: I tried boolean before in the same code but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
    Scanner keyBoard=new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;
    ArrayList<Integer>numbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean containsDuplicate = false;
    for (int i=0;i<6;i++){
        System.out.println("Number "+(i+1)+" : ");
        number=keyBoard.nextInt();
        numbers.add(number);
        for (int j=0;j<numbers.size()-1;j++){
            if (numbers.get(j) == number) {
                System.out.println(number+" is duplicate");
                containsDuplicate = true
                break;
            }
        } 
        if(containsDuplicate){
           break;
        }
    }
    for (int k=0;k<numbers.size()-1;k++){
        System.out.print(numbers.get(k));
    }
```

Comment: Thx, but the program should stop when the  duplicate number written and then print out arrayList

Comment: what is the problem you are facing ? is it the extra number also printed? you need to use break twice